# Wazuh windows agent cant connect after long disconnect

Tags: wazuh, ossec

My windows Wazuh agent registers properly and agent is visible.
However when computer is turned off for few hours, and you boot in it , it doesnt connect to manager. I can provide logs ,debug logs if you need this information to diagnose the problem. Its on VM and I red that problematic here is socket on server side that doesnt close and remains in state `FIN_WAIT_2`.
Here is link with my problem on github
https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/17706
How to get windows agent to automatically connect at startup? Any fixes or work-arounds?